# Cannot find name even though its referenced

Tags: typescript, lodash

I have a problem. In my `app.component.ts` I reference the following:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/index.d.ts" />
```

However, in file `User.component.ts`, I use some of the imported definitions:

```
_.find(..)
```

Even though typescript sees the `typings/index.d.ts` file, which has following:

```
/// <reference path="globals/angular-protractor/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/core-js/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/jasmine/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/selenium-webdriver/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="modules/lodash/index.d.ts" />
```

I've checked - and yes, `modules/lodash/index.d.ts` exists.

It still throws an error of:

> Cannot find name '_'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see where you are using underscore in this project?

Comment: Do you have an import statement : `import * as _ from 'lodash';`